# Function to choose image file one by one automatically in R

Tags: r, loops, functor, google-vision

I have a folder with 100+ images. I want to run an google vision analysis on each of them in R. Instead of running the analysis on one image at a time I want to create a function which will access each image one by one and run the analysis.

Using following code:

`getGooglevisionResponse(file.choose(),feature = 'text_detection')`

I am using `file.choose()` to choose one file at a time but I want to create a loop which will dynamically select each image and run the analysis on them ..
Used `list.files()` but getting below error
`the following condition has length >1 and only the first element will be used`

found one post but that is in python  unable to replicate it in R

https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Google%20Vision/multiple_features_request_single_API_call.py

Comment: You might want to take a look at `list.files`

Comment: actually yes .. it does select multiple image but when it comes to running the analysis its throwing an error .. it's not creating a loop where it selects  one file runs the analysis then goes to second..

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code, you just need to use `lapply` and `list.files`.

```
fil <- list.files("<myImgDir>", full.names = T)
out <- lapply(fil, getGoogleVisionResponse, feature = 'text_detection'))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but the error remains, Mentioned the code already..
`getGooglevisionResponse(file.choose(),feature = 'text_detection')' ..
`file.choose` only chooses one file and runs text detection .. i need a function in tht place which will choose those images one by one and run the analysis

Comment: @SumaiyaKhatun I have this sense you are trying this -> getGooglevisionResponse(list.files(), feature = 'text_detection') <- Am I correct? If so, that is incorrect.

Comment: yes you are correct ... i was doing this only .... can you please suggest any other way? the code you gave is giving error..

Comment: I made and edit to my answer. Replace the `"<myImgDir>"` with the path to your images as a string, (`"C:\MyFolder"`). You will need to make sure that this path contains only images you are trying to process. If you get an error, post it here.

Comment: hey thank you for all the help.. I did use your code but the problem is R is not recognizing `getGoogleVisionResponse` within lapply...Error is `object 'getGooglevisionResponse' not found`.... and when I am using `getGoogleVisionResponse(fil, feature = 'text_detection')` ... error is `In if (stringr::str_count(imagePath, "http") > 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: I also tried below code .. do know if it is correct
`Address <- setwd("path to image folder")`
`fil <- list.files(Address, pattern = '*.jpeg')`
`for(i in 1:length(fil)) {
  assign(fil[i],
  pic <-readJPEG(Address, fil))
Vsn <- getGoogleVisionResponse(pic,feature = 'TEXT_DETECTION')
}`
Error I m getting is ' unable to open 'path to image folder'   'In addition: Warning message:
In readJPEG(Address, fil) : NAs introduced by coercion'

Comment: I had copied and pasted you code without looking up the library. You have a typo in your original function call, R is case sensitive afterall, which I pasted into mine. The function name is `getGoogleVisionResponse`. I have updated my post to reflect this. You shouldn't get the `object ... not found error` any longer.

Comment: Hey .. the problem remains the same .. the function works 
`getGoogleVisionResponse(imagepath,feature=())`..in your code the path is missing .. getting the error 
`getGoogleVisionResponse` ..and when I added the path which is `fil` .. the same error is coming ..
`the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: `fil` is not a path, `fil` is a list of paths. `lapply` iterates over them, applying the `getGoogle...` function to each element. That is why you are getting the `length >1` error. I recommend reading up on working directories, and apply functions.